Failed to load image in digiKam
I have been using digiKam since several years. Recently, I moved from Ubuntu to Fedora 40. I have a fresh installation of digiKam 8.3.0 and for some reason it fails to open any image:

It also fails with MP4 videos, but MPEG videos work. All the paths in the database and in the collection are fine, as well as the location of the files, and permissions for the user.

Yes, if I go to the directory where the images are, and I just double click the files, they open fine with the image viewer application.

I found a solution by downloading the app image directly from their website. It is a slightly older version, but works fine.
